# How to rename file and folder with the same case as a reference one

Tags: linux, bash

I have to rename a complete folder tree ('target') recursively so that it has
the same files and folders name as on the file server ('server').

*Example. On the `'target'`*:

```
./target 
./target/FILE 
./target/dir2 
./target/dir2/File2 
./target/DIR1 
./target/DIR1/file1
```

*On the `'server'`*:

```
./target 
./target/file 
./target/DIR2 
./target/DIR2/File2 
./target/dir1 
./target/dir1/File1
```

I'm quite sure that if the filenames are the same (comparing in lower case)
the files are the same (maybe I can add a checksum comparing).
Final result should be that 'target' has the same filenames as the 'server'. 
I've tried with bash (should be the best solution)... but bash hate me! Any clue? TY!

Comment: I must be missing something, but isn't it easyer to just copy the directory?

Comment: I can't quite understand what you want. Can you try to explain this again?

Comment: The directories and the files on the server have different character case from the 'target'. I must uniform the case before use rsync (character sensitive), so copy is not a solution (it's almost 2Tb of files!). T.y.

Comment: If you want to synchronize *server* to *target*, the easiest way from the targets machine is `rsync -uav --delete server:/target /path/above_target/`, or from the server `rsync -uav --delete ./target target:/path/above_target` (note: no trailing `'/'` on the source in either). Both forms will copy all *server* files recursively within the `./target` directory to the `target` directory on the `target` machine (you could make this easier with different names) All files not existing on `server` are `--delete`ed.

Answer (score 0):

first, create 2 files, `source.txt` and `target.txt` containing the directories as printed in your question

You can achieve this for instance like this:

```
(cd path/to/the/server;find . -type d) > target.txt
(cd path/to/the/source;find . -type d) > source.txt
```

Then run this shell:

```
while read target_dir
do
    fixed_name=$(grep -i ^$target_dir\$ source.txt)
    if [ ! -z "$fixed_name" ] ; then
      (cd path/to/the/server;mv $target_dir $fixed_name)
    fi
done < target.txt
```

Basically, for each line of `target.txt` file, it looks the correct-case counterpart in the `source.txt` file. If found, then issues the rename command, located in the `path/to/the/server` directory.

Comment: if the answer is not really answering to a question you did not ask, please edit your question accordingly, and I'll try to adapt my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jean: u guide me to the solution! It's a little bit more complex:

```
#!/bin/bash
# 160912
# match filenames char-cases on target path as in server path
# usage : $0 targetDir serverDir

TARGET_PATH=$1

MAKE_EQUAL()
{
  while read server_name
  do
      new_target_name=$(grep -i ^$server_name\$ targetList.txt)
      if [ ! -z "$new_target_name" ] && [ "$server_name" != "$new_target_name" ] ; then
        echo "  $new_target_name --> $server_name"
        (cd $TARGET_PATH;mv $new_target_name $server_name)
      fi
  done < serverList.txt
}

if [ ! -d "$1" -o ! -d "$2" ] ; then
    echo "Paths not found!"
    exit 0
fi

# Change directories changing depth level until is the last directory level
DIRLEVEL=1 
LASTLEVEL=0
(cd $2;find . -maxdepth $DIRLEVEL -type d) > serverList.txt
while [ "$LASTLEVEL" == "0" ]
  do
    echo "Match directory level $DIRLEVEL:"
    (cd $1;find . -maxdepth $DIRLEVEL -type d) > targetList.txt
    MAKE_EQUAL
    DIRLEVEL=`expr $DIRLEVEL + 1` 
    (cd $2;find . -maxdepth $DIRLEVEL -type d) > nextServerList.txt
    diff nextServerList.txt serverList.txt > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
      LASTLEVEL=1
    else
      mv nextServerList.txt serverList.txt
    fi
  done

echo "Match files:"

(cd $1;find . -type f) > targetList.txt
(cd $2;find . -type f) > serverList.txt
MAKE_EQUAL

echo "Done!"
```